# how to return in connection.query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a problem...
I wanted to return "A" but The result was "B"
I don't know what to do
Please help me

my code:

```
async function getID(){

    let sql = 'SELECT * from id'

    connection.query(sql, (err, rows) => {
        if (err)
            throw err;

        console.log(rows)
        return "A"
        // return rows

    })
    return "B"
}

let list = getCredit();
list.then(console.log);
console.log(list)
```

My results

```
    [2022/06/13 21:34:29.548] Promise { 'B' }
    [2022/06/13 21:34:29.549] B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing here callback with promises.
To reach what you want, wrap your function in a promise:

```js
function getID(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    let sql = 'SELECT * from id'

    connection.query(sql, (err, rows) => {
        if (err){
           reject(err)
        }else{
           resolve(rows);
        }
    })

  })
}

let list = getCredit();
list.then(console.log);
console.log(list)
```